# __sync_bool_compare_and_swap Compiler Flags and Includes

Tags: c++, memory-management, cas

I am working on a lock free data structure, and am trying to CAS pointers.

When using compare and swap, what flags should I pass into the compiler?
I have gotten a license for http://locklessinc.com/ memory allocator.
I am also using netbeans 7.

Currently The only flags I have are under the linker, -march=native -lllalloc.

However when I run the program I get weird memory issues.
I think I may be missing a flag or two...
Also netbeans says "unable to resolve identifier __sync_bool_compare_and_swap" but it still compiles it.

Anyone have any ideas?

Data Structure:

```
struct Ambigous
{
    short type;
    union{
        struct{
            bool inCleanup;
            KEY key;
            VALUE value;
        };
        Ambigous* volatile list[MAIN_SIZE];//CHANGED ordering, still have netbeans error
    };

};
```

My Compare and swap code

```
bool res= __sync_bool_compare_and_swap(&(local->list[pos]), current_node, new_node);
```

How I allocate memory:

```
Ambigous *temp_spine = (Ambigous *) calloc(1,sizeof (Ambigous));
```

Comment: A quick question, why is `list` declared `volatile`? Have you tried looking at the generated assembler?

Comment: Ah, that may be my issue, list should not be volatile, rather each element inside list should be volatile.

Comment: No. Why `volatile` at all? What service is it providing?

Comment: The compare and swap is done on elements inside the list, and I was under the impression it needed to be volatile because of that.  (I rearranged that line, it now does not show an error, but still has memory issues)

Comment: Compare and swap should give you all that you need. [Volatile: Almost Useless for Multi-Threaded Programming](http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2007/11/30/volatile-almost-useless-for-multi-threaded-programming/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`__sync_bool_compare_and_swap` is a GCC intrinsic. You don't need any particular compiler flags for it; however, your IDE won't be able to find its definition, because it doesn't have one. And it may not work on other compilers; eg, the Visual Studio compilers call it [`InterlockedCompareExchange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683560%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

As for where your problem is, it's hard to say without seeing the rest of your code. Lockless algorithms are *very* tricky to get right; it's all too easy to miss some small race condition. Stick to locks unless you have a very good reason to do otherwise.

Comment: I am in research, and the memory errors are not in algorithm, its in either the compare and swap or more likely the memory allocator.
The reason I know its not the algorithm is because the memory errors are null exceptions, after a null check, and the portion of the algorithm I am testing doesn't remove any values inserted

Comment: Just because you haven't removed any values doesn't mean you're not seeing stale NULL reads from before the insert or something. Again, it's not possible to debug this further without full code.

Comment: You are right they are very tricky, A position I assumed would not become null, became null doing a resize process that I didn't anticipate. I only found the bug because I ran all the threads with the same data files by mistakes :).